# How to call LiveData again

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a LiveData for fetching data from server and this LiveData may receive some time error response, so i need to fetch data again.
can i notify that data resource that refresh server request again?

```
val movies : LiveData<Result<Movies>>? by lazy {
        model.getMovies()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MutableLiveData to achieve this. For example you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val movies: MutableLiveData<Result<Movies>>? by lazy {
    model.getMovies()
}

fun retryGetMovies() {
    val response = model.getMovies()
    movies.postValue(response)  
}
```